# Laravel - Log In with only one device

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Is there any way that I can allow user to login only from one device?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Well, you would need to check at a central place, if there is an already existing session for the user that currently want to log in - and if yes, delete all existing sessions.

The central place would proably be when the login happens or inside an auth middleware.

To delete all existing sessions for the user you can run

```php
DB::table('sessions')->where('user_id', $user->id)->delete();
```

**Log in only from one device, f. ex. Laptop**

That is probably not possible as each device would need to send a unique identifier - which it doesn't. As example, your Laptop would need to send a unique identifier to the Laravel system, so that your Laravel application would know, that it is the Laptop the login is coming from.

The login forms normally only takes a username/email and a password, so no unique property to identify your Laptop.

You could probably check for browser user agent or things like this, but that is all fakeable and does not guarantee a 100% proof identification of the device.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. I don't want to check if user already logged in. I want to allow user that can login only from one device, for example my lap top.

Comment: I updated my answer to explain a bit about the device.

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot

Comment: Happy to help. If I could help, feel free to mark this answer as solved and mark my answer.

Answer (score -1):

You can use deviceInspect middleware and check user agent (it could be fake as @codedge said) and use it after auth middleware

As you can see the user will be authenticated but routes will be protected by device

Create middleware

```
class DeviceInspect
{

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $user = Auth::user(); //or $request->user()

        // TODO get enabled device/s from datebase for $user - by userId
        $enabledDevice = "Dalvik/2.2.0 (Linux; U; Android 10.0.1; AM-A89R Build/NMB55D)"; //example
        $currentDevice = $request->userAgent(); //or $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        //it could be fake like codedge said

        if ($enabledDevice !== $currentDevice) {
            $data = array(
                "device" => false,
                "message" => "your message to user",
            );
            return response([$data], 401); // or something else
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

add this to App\Http\Kernel

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        ...
        'device' => 'App\Http\Middleware\DeviceInspect',
    ];
```

and use it like below

```
//in controller
class SomeController extends Controller {  
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->middleware(['auth', "device"]);
    }
}
```

or

```
//Or in routes
Route::get('/profil', function () {
        //
})->middleware(['auth', 'device']);


or

Route::group(['prefix' => '/v1/data', 'namespace' => 'Api\V1', 'as' => 'api.', 'middleware' => ['auth:api', 'device']], function () {
    Route::resource('activity', 'Data\DataController', ['only' => ['index', 'show']]);
});
```